# Pinterest Get Client_id in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, pinterest

Please tell me how to get `Client_id` for use in Pinterest iOS SDK 2.3

```
let imageUrl = NSURL(string: "http://prophitmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Pinterest-Logo.png")
let sourceUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
let pinterest : Pinterest = Pinterest()

pinterest.setValue("XXXXXX", forKey: "clientId")
if(pinterest.canPinWithSDK()){
    pinterest.createPinWithImageURL(imageUrl, sourceURL:sourceUrl, description:"DemoPinit")
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code.

Comment: You need to create an app [--here--](https://developers.pinterest.com/apps/). It will give you an id to use as your client id.

Comment: Thank Now i Create Pinterest App . ( http://picture.in.th/id/18db9e696595a8fa0f1d613cd2587a45 ) And i try use App id . But SDK Can show Not valid Client_id